# feathersjs - how to remotely retrieve available services

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-hook

I want to load service collections into my front end without knowing a priori what they are.  I assume I can set up hook on the server that simply walks the service directory and determines the services (subdirectory names) and passes this information back.  In fact that information should be in the app instance as a result of the `app.configure(services)` call?

I've done this before using a `get` with a special `_id` that gets hooked and returns other information than a collection record.  My issue is that without knowing a service name how can I form a socket request of the featherjs server that gets hooked (like `get`).   I suppose I could always have at least one known service (like `users`) that I can add that hook to but just wondering if there is a way to do what I want (find out without knowing any service names).

It looks like there are application level hooks https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/application.html#hookshooks so how can I call one of those via socket client and get the result back on the client.

IMHO this should be part of the client api.  This would avoid hard coding of service names or having to put them in some custom build config file for the client.

Answer (score 1):

There are security reasons why this is not available by default and returning a list of all services on the client should be done in a way specific to your application.

On the server you can get an object of all available services via [app.services](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/application.html#services) which can be made available to the client fairly straightforwardly through a [custom service](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html):

```
app.use('/', {
  async find () {
    const services = Object.keys(app.services);

    return { services };
  }
});
```

Now going to the root level (`/`) will list the names of all available services. You probably also want to make sure to secure the call accordingly so not everybody can know all the endpoints they can attack.

Comment: so since you say I need a "custom" service then answer to my question is no, correct?  One MUST have at least one service name known to the client a priori in order to discover the other available services. I suppose then using the 'user' service as I proposed would be the best option as almost always there will be such a service for access security.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then. The client has to know about some discovery mechanism so why not use what is already there? Since the name is known, a root level service is a good place for retrieving the information you need.